# find -regex doesn't work with {} specifier

Tags: regex, linux, find

I'm trying to run the following:

```
find /var/log/sa/ -regex ".*/sa[0\-3]\{2\}"
```

However, this returns no results. I can see in `/var/log/sa/` that files exist, both formats of `sa##` and `sar##` -- I only want to match the former.

```
ll /var/log/sa/
total 40992
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec  1 23:50 sa01
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec  2 23:50 sa02
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec  3 23:50 sa03
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec  4 23:50 sa04
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec  5 23:50 sa05
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec  6 23:50 sa06
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec  7 23:50 sa07
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec  8 23:50 sa08
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec  9 23:50 sa09
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec 10 23:50 sa10
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec 11 23:50 sa11
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec 12 23:50 sa12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec 13 23:50 sa13
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719940 Dec 14 23:50 sa14
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec 15 23:50 sa15
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec 16 23:50 sa16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec 17 23:50 sa17
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec 18 23:50 sa18
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec 19 23:50 sa19
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec 20 23:50 sa20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec 21 23:50 sa21
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Dec 22 23:50 sa22
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 669932 Dec 23 22:10 sa23
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Nov 24 23:50 sa24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Nov 25 23:50 sa25
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Nov 26 23:50 sa26
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Nov 27 23:50 sa27
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Nov 28 23:50 sa28
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Nov 29 23:50 sa29
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 719892 Nov 30 23:50 sa30
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec  1 23:53 sar01
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec  2 23:53 sar02
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec  3 23:53 sar03
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec  4 23:53 sar04
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec  5 23:53 sar05
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec  6 23:53 sar06
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec  7 23:53 sar07
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec  8 23:53 sar08
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec  9 23:53 sar09
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec 10 23:53 sar10
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec 11 23:53 sar11
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec 12 23:53 sar12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec 13 23:53 sar13
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 674697 Dec 14 23:53 sar14
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec 15 23:53 sar15
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec 16 23:53 sar16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec 17 23:53 sar17
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec 18 23:53 sar18
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec 19 23:53 sar19
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec 20 23:53 sar20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec 21 23:53 sar21
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Dec 22 23:53 sar22
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Nov 23 23:53 sar23
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Nov 24 23:53 sar24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Nov 25 23:53 sar25
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Nov 26 23:53 sar26
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Nov 27 23:53 sar27
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Nov 28 23:53 sar28
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Nov 29 23:53 sar29
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 673355 Nov 30 23:53 sar30
```

Comment: Try `".*/sa[0-3]\{2\}"`

Comment: Tried that, no dice

Comment: Can you provide a few real filenames you have there? (no `##`, real digits)

Comment: In your example the filenames should be `sa0{2}` (for example)

Comment: yep, updated my question with example data

Comment: This should work `".*/sa[0-3][0-9]"`

Comment: `me@host:~$ find /var/log/sa/ -regex ".*/sa[0-3]{2}"` returns nothing still.

Comment: Just updated my last comment :) Let me know if the new one works

Comment: Perfect, that worked! If you want to put it up as an answer, with maybe an explanation as to why the `{}` specifier doesn't work, that'd be super.

Comment: Added the answer, you can check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
 find /var/log/sa/ -regex ".*/sa[0-3][0-9]"
```

Since the first char after the `sa` should be `0/1/2/3` and the second char should be any digit.

The reason for the `{..}` to not work is that GNU's find doesn't support the `{from,to}` syntax. [The default regex in `find` is `emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#emacs-regular-expression-syntax), but the version used by GNU don't support the `{..}` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /var/log/sa/ -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/sa[0-3]{2}'
```

You have to use posix-egrep.